# Find the average number for each user

Tags: php, mysqli

First off, I am fairly new to coding. I try to do my due diligence before coming here for advice.

I am trying to write a function that will query the database for a users numbers and get the average for each user.

```
function getUserAverage($userID) {
    //loop through user totals & calculate average for each user
    $sql = "select p.userID, p.user, p.number ";
    $sql .= "from " . DB_PREFIX . "numbers p ";
    $sql .= "inner join " . DB_PREFIX . "users u on p.userID = u.userID ";
    $sql .= "where u.userID = " . $user->userID . " ";
    $sql .= "order by u.lastname, u.firstname";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        //player average of numbers
        $tba = ROUND(AVG(`number`),2);

    }
    $query->free;
    return $tba;
    }
```

The result I am hoping to get is something like:

user1 = 14.5
user2 = 35.8
user3 - 7.4

I have written code to get the average numbers for all, but the need is to get by individual user.

```
//Average Numbers

$sql_avgNum = "SELECT ROUND(AVG(`number`),2) AS `Average` \n"
. "FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "numbers` \n";
$data = $mysqli->query($sql_avgNum);
$result_avgNum = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
echo ' <tr class="altrow"><td> Average Number: </td><td> ' . 
$result_avgNum[0] . ' </td></tr>';

//End Average Numbers
```

Comment: you could get an average over a group of numbers - that s how average works. How do you intend getting an average Per user with only 1 value? If you have multple values PER user, you could find the average - i.e. like your SAT.

Comment: I have this working to get the total average number. (added code i am using for that. Maybe I just need to build of that?

Answer (score 0):

for count average of individual data you must do it using group by. Further reference of group by is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp):

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure, but I think that this is what you're looking for:

```
function getUserAverage($userID) {
    // loop through user totals & calculate average for each user
    $sql = "SELECT p.userID, u.user, AVG(p.number) AS 'avarage' ";
    $sql .= "FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "numbers p ";
    $sql .= "INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "users u ON(p.userID = u.userID) ";
    $sql .= "WHERE p.userID = " . $user->userID . " ";
    $sql .= "GROUP BY p.userID ";
    $sql .= "ORDER BY u.lastname, u.firstname";
    $query = $mysqli->query($sql);

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        //player average of numbers
        $tba = $row['avarage'];

    }

    $query->free;
    return $tba;
}
```

Comment: This is close i think. I removed the WHERE and ran it in SQL and get the desired results. When I call the function though, I get a Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in /includes/functions.php on line 320

Comment: If your query has an error $query var will be bill or false. That's probably why you're getting that error.